# QTableWidget Tag on Items

Tags: qt, tags, qtablewidget

I was wondering how I could set a 'tag' on items/rows/columns on a QTableWidgetItem. For exmaple, in C# it is called a tag on the Listview. I need this because I need to link an item to each row.

```
ListViewItem.Tag = myObject;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be accomplished using [QTableWidgetItem::setData()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html#setData) and a bit of `QVariant` magic. For example:

```
// Allow your object type to be converted to a QVariant:
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( ObjectType* );

// Define a role to store your object under:
const int ObjectRole = Qt::UserRole + 1;

QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem();
item->setData( ObjectRole, QVariant::fromValue(myObject) );
```

and then to retrieve your object:

```
ObjectType *myObject = item->data( ObjectRole ).value<ObjectType*>();
```

Easy right? ;)

See also: [Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE), [QVariant::fromValue()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#fromValue), [QVariant::value()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#value)